# Dictionary will not output the values to the key entered

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file that contains a bunch of movies in the order of 'Title', 'year', 'genre', 'director', 'actors'. I'm trying to make a dictionary that has 'movie title', 'year' for the keys and have the 'actors' as the value(s). I do not get any errors but I can't get the values from the dictionary to output. I think it is entering the if statement but does not execute anything because nothing is found. Can someone tell me what is happening here?

```
movie_list = "movies.txt"
in_file = open(movie_list, 'r')
in_file.readline()

def list_maker(in_file):
    movie1 = input("Enter in a movie: ")
    movie2 = input("Enter in another movie: ")

    d = {}

    for line in in_file:
        l = line.split(",")
        title, year = l[0], l[1]  # only want the title and year
        people = []
        for i in range(4, len(l)): 
            people.append(l[i])
        d[title_year] = people

    # print(d) # just checking the dictionary is working
            if movie1 in d or movie2 in d:
                print("The movie {key} and {key2} actors are {value1}, 
                {value2}".format(key=movie1,key2=movie2, 
                value1=d.get(movie1), value2=d.get(movie2)))

list_maker(in_file)
```

Comment: It does *not* enter the if loop. If you add `('Titanic',1997)` as key, and you do a lookup with `'Titanic'`, that will fail.

Comment: Thank you for that. I did as you both suggested @Willem Van Onsem. I also shifted the if condition to be inside the  nested four loop which made sense to me that it would check every time it went through the loop to see if the movie matched. But I still don't get  an output.

Comment: @Mr_U4913 couldn't add you into the same comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of updates to you code. The behavior will depend on if you want the user to input the "title" and "year", or just the "title". Trying to keep your code as close to the original, this requires the user to input the movie as `<Title><Year>`, (e.g `The Dark Knight2008`). If this is not your desired behavior, please comment and I can make updates unless you can make the changes:

```
movie_list = "movies.txt"
infile = open(movie_list, 'r') # needed to use different
in_file = infile.readlines()   # variable names here

def list_maker(in_file):
    movie1 = input("Enter in a movie: ")       #TitleYear
    movie2 = input("Enter in another movie: ") #TitleYear

    d = {}

    for line in in_file:
        l = line.split(",")
        title_year = l[0]+l[1]  # only want the title and year
        people = []
        people = l[4::]
        d[title_year] = [p.strip('\n') for p in people] 

    for key in d.keys():
        if movie1 in d or movie2 in key:
            print("The movie {key} and {key2} actors are {value1}, {value2}".format(key=movie1,key2=movie2, value1=', '.join(d[movie1]), 
            value2=', '.join(d[movie2])))

list_maker(in_file)
```

***Edit***:
***Update with additional request***: To use the actors found in those movies, and search the dictionary for those "values" and print the movies that have those actors in it:

```
movie_list = "movies.txt"
infile = open(movie_list, 'r')
in_file = infile.readlines()

def list_maker(in_file):
    movie1 = input("Enter in a movie: ")
    movie2 = input("Enter in another movie: ")

    d = {}
    all_actors = []             # Create a list for all actors in all movies

    for line in in_file:
        l = line.split(",")
        title_year = l[0]+l[1]  # only want the title and year
        people = []
        people = l[4::]
        all_actors.extend(l.strip('\n') for l in l[4::]) # add actors to all_actors list
        d[title_year] = [p.strip('\n') for p in people]

    for actor in all_actors:               # for each actor in the all_actors list
        for movie, cast in d.iteritems():  # check each movie
            if actor in cast:              # and check if actor is in this movie
                print '{a} is in {m}'.format(a=actor, m=movie)

list_maker(in_file)
```

Comment: Okay, question though: if I wanted to use the actors found in those movies, and search my dictionary for those "values" and print the movies that have those actors in it, how would I go about it?

Comment: maybe something like this: try `for actor in actors:
        for movie, cast in d.iteritems():
            if actor in cast:
                print movie`. If that's hard to read (sorry, code doesn't format well in comments) let me know and I can include that in the answer so it's easier to read.

Comment: I've tried to manipulate it to the way I want it but its not working. Could you show me what I'm doing wrong? This is what I tried (among a few other manipulations):
    for actor in d.values():
        for movie, cast in d.iteritems():
            if actor in cast:
                print(movie)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention in my last comment that we have to create a list of actors, and that's why the code didn't work for you. I've updated the answer to include new code that only prints out each actor and the movie they are in. You could also create a `list` for each actor and `.append()` each movie that has that actor in it. If you want I can update the code to do that. Just let me know how you want the final output to look like.

Comment: That is awesome. Like holy crap dude, that's impressive. Thank you for helping me with that. I just started programming and I've learned a lot in the past 3 weeks but haven't been able to completely get the logic down for breaking problems up and what not. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Oh no worries, I *completely* know that feeling, I know I still suck as breaking problems down. That's really good you've learned a lot in only 3 weeks of programming! Keep up the good work and you'll be impressing yourself in no time. Again, glad to help! cheers!